# How to use dart future.sync method

Tags: dart, dart-async

When i try to use future.sync from class future like

```dart
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
    var fur3 = new Future<int>(() => 45);
    int z = Future.sync(fur3);
    print(z);
}
```

i've got the error message

> Breaking on exception: object of type NoSuchMethodError

Do i use future.sync in the wrong way?

My second question is

```dart
import 'package:async/async.dart';

void main() {
  var fur1 = new Future<int>(() => 45);
    fur1.then((value) {
      return value;
    }).catchError((err) => print('catchError1: ${err}'));
}
```

why when i try to import async library from package, i've got compiler message

> Breaking on exception: object of type TypeError
>   Undefined class 'Future'

what am i do here wrong?

Comment: What did you try to accomplish using `Future.sync()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You don't pass a future into `Future.sync()` but a closure to be executed immediately.

```dart
Future z = Future.sync(() => print('bla'));
```

2. async is an internal package. You import it using

   import 'dart:async';

Internal packages don't need to be added to `pubspec.yaml` dependencies because they are always available. The different import statement is related to that.

Comment: You can indeed pass either a future or a computation to Future.sync https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.2/dart-async/Future/Future.sync.html. I'm pretty sure the error is trying to assign the return of Future.sync to an int variable.

Comment: Günter, what does it means "executed immediately"?

Comment: As in immediately like code lines that are executed consecutively in contrary to enlisting a function or closure into a queue to be invoked later. The later is what async and Futures are about. In Dart you only have one thread by default and you want the CPU to do meaningful work while waiting for server responses, user input, ... . Code invoked by events runs as long as it can actively do something meaningful, if it can't because it has to wait it enqueues a callback (what you pass to `.then (...)`

Comment: into the event queue to be execute when the response arrives. Because there is only one thread only one event handler can run at a time. All others in the queue have to wait until the former completes or yields.

Comment: If my closure returns a Future or is an async function itself, would all execution on the thread wait for the closure to return? Is that what sync() does? I can't figure it out, the docs are vague, in the source it just seems to run the closure and handles errors from what I can tell, which I could have done without wrapping it in Future.sync(). What am I missing?

Comment: Then you don't need `Future.sync(...)`, `Future.sync(...)` is just to artificially create a `Future`. If you already have one, it doesn't make sense to use it. `Future.sync()` means "Returns a future containing the result of immediately calling computation." (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.sync.html), so the computation is not enqueued first to be processed eventually, but instead immediately.